# Sony Vegas Text Parser?

Tags: vegas-pro

I'm working on one of those videos where there's a voice over and text follows it, one sentence appearing at a time. I lose quite a lot of time having to generate or copy media and having to "feed it" once sentence at a time. I have complete control over the format of the text, so is there any way for me to feed 25 sentences to Vegas and have it generate 25 media elements for me, putting one sentence to each of them? I'm open to ANY suggestion, as the method I use now just takes a lot of time alttabing and copying sentence by sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Vegasaur's [TextGen](http://vegasaur.com/text-generation-wizard).
It can import text from SRT, SUB and CSV files, or you can create 25 markers, paste 25 sentences and generate 25 media elements (one sentence for each text media)